# Matlab: Subscript + squeeze conveniently

Tags: matlab

I'm using matlab and am quite new to it. I'm used to Java and other langauges.

Some background: I'm manipulating images, I work with the imread, imshow etc. commands. I want to store multiple images in an array.

So what I do is

```
img_list = zeroes(num_images, 1200, 1600, 3) % height,width,RGB
```

and then I load the images with `img_list(i,:,:,:) = my_image;`  iteratively. That is all working fine.

Now I can display the images as I want by doing `imshow(squeeze(img_list(1,:,:,:)))`. I can't stand this. I would like something as simple as `imshow(img_list(1))`.

Any idea how I can do this?

I definetly am open to change the type of `img_list`. Any hints is appreciated. Maybe I could do something so all my images in `img_list` don't have to be of the same size?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html). Each element of a cell array is a container that can hold a variable of any type and size. You access the element of a cell array as `array(i)` (which returns a 1-by-1 cell). To access the *contents* of an element of a cell array, you use curly brackets, i.e `array{i}`. Also have a look at [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html), which allows you to perform operations on each image.

```
%# initialize the cell array
img_list = cell(num_images);

%# add an image to the cell array
img_list{4} = someImage;

%# display the image
imshow(img_list{4})

%# display only the red channel
imshow(img_list{4}(:,:,3))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out a little bit later and return with what I think. Most likely this is the answer I'm looking for. Thannks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Using cell arrays, as Jonas suggested, is probably the Right Thing -- especially if you want to be able to have images of different sizes. But it's worth mentioning that you can make the simple 4-dimensional-array approach a little nicer: make the image number the last index instead of the first. Then you can say `img_list(:,:,:,i) = my_image;` and `imshow(img_list(:,:,:,1));` with no need for squeezing. That's probably a little better for memory locality (hence for performance) too, though it won't be any better than using cell arrays.

Comment: That seems like a smart side note! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define a local anonymous function:

```
  % Get image list from somewhere.
img_list = ...;
% ...

  % Easy-access to individual frames.
nth_image = @(k) squeeze(img_list(k,:,:,:));
image_count = size(img_list,1);

  % Loop over images.
% ...
```

This allows you to write the following list:

```
  % Process each image.
for i = 1 : image_count,
    img = nth_image(i);
    % ...
end
```

If you have multiple image lists or this pattern occurs often, you can write more generic functions:

```
function [ img ] = get_nth_image ( img_list, k )
    img = squeeze(img_list(k,:,:,:));
end
function [ img_list ] = set_nth_image ( img_list, img, k )
    img_list(k,:,:,:) = img;
end
```